# Create custom excel report from wizard in odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to generate an excel report from wizard using `report_xlsx` module but i am getting below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/kabeer/Projects/Odoo15ce/odoo/custom_addons/report_xlsx/controllers/main.py", line 76, in report_download
> response = self.report_routes(
> File "/home/kabeer/Projects/Odoo15ce/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)
> File "/home/kabeer/Projects/Odoo15ce/odoo/custom_addons/report_xlsx/controllers/main.py", line 32, in report_routes
> data.update(json.loads(data.pop("options")))
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 10; 2 is required

Here is what i did.

***.xml**

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <odoo>
            <record id="open_purchase_order_print_menu" model="ir.actions.report">
                <field name="name">Open PO</field>
                <field name="model">open.po</field>
                <field name="report_type">xlsx</field>
                <field name="report_name">transight.open_po</field>
                <field name="report_file">transight.open_po</field>
                <field name="print_report_name">'Purchase Order'</field>
                <!-- <field name="binding_model_id" ref="purchase.model_purchase_order"/> -->
                <field name="binding_type">report</field>
            </record>
            <record id="open_po_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
              <field name="name">open.po.form</field>
              <field name="model">open.po</field>
              <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Open PO">
                    <group>
                      <field name="mode" required="1"/>
                    </group>
                    <group col="4">
                      <field name="purchase_order_id"
                        widget="many2many_tags"
                        attrs="{'invisible':[('mode','=','partnumber')]}"/>
                      <field name="partnumber" attrs="{'invisible':[('mode','=','po')]}"/>
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                      <button string="Print" name="action_print" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                      <button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
              </field>
            </record>
            <record id="action_open_po" model="ir.actions.act_window">
              <field name="name">Open PO</field>
              <field name="res_model">open.po</field>
              <field name="view_mode">form</field>
              <field name="target">new</field>
            </record>
            <menuitem id="menu_open_po_action" name="Open PO" parent="mrp.menu_mrp_configuration" action="action_open_po" sequence="4"/>
          </odoo>
```

***.py**

```
    from odoo import fields,models,api,_


    class OpenPOXlsx(models.AbstractModel):
        _name = 'report.transight.open_po'
        _inherit = 'report.report_xlsx.abstract'
        def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, partners):
            print('data',data)
            for obj in partners:
                report_name = 'Excel Report test'
                # One sheet by partner
                sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(report_name[:31])
                bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
                sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hi Am here', bold)

    class OpenPO(models.TransientModel):
        _name = 'open.po'
        _description = 'OpenPO'

        purchase_order_id = fields.Many2many('purchase.order',string='Purchase Order')
        partnumber = fields.Char(string="Partnumber")
        mode = fields.Selection([('partnumber','Part Number'),('po','Purchase Order')],string="Filter by")

        def action_print(self):


            if self.mode == 'po':
                query = """my query %s """

                self.env.cr.execute(query,(tuple(self.purchase_order_id.ids),))
                datas = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
                print('data---------',datas)
            # return self.env.ref('account_batch_payment.action_print_batch_payment').report_action(self, config=False)

            return self.env.ref('transight.open_purchase_order_print_menu').report_action(self,data=datas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dictfetchall()](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ce4d52fbbf400d911901e09d562e06984447639a/odoo/sql_db.py#L277) method returns a list of dicts and `report_action` is expecting `data` (datas) to be a dict.

In previous Odoo versions, we pass record data using `form` key, for example:

```
datas = {
  'ids': active_ids,
  'model': 'hr.contribution.register',
  'form': self.read()[0]
}
```

To fix this issue, add the fetched values to datas:

```
values = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
datas['values'] = values
```

Then use `values` key in  `generate_xlsx_report` method

Make sure that `datas` is a dictionary before calling `report_action`